# Disable raycaster physics inside dynamic-body

Tags: javascript, physics, aframe

I need some help with AFRAME, im new and im stuck with a problem.

I have the next code.

```
<a-entity dynamic-body id="a-pibot" collada-model="#model-pibot" scale="5 5 5" rotation="0 -5 0" position="2.14 0.1 -0.12">
      <a-entity id="secondaryCamera" position="0.1 0.02 0" rotation="-20 -90 0">
        <!-- Create a second third-person camera which cant be controlled, the Pibot camera -->
        <a-camera spectator="canvas:#spectatorDiv;" active="false" wasd-controls-enabled="false" look-controls-enabled="false"></a-camera>
      </a-entity>
      <a-entity id="positionSensor" dynamic-body="shape:none;" raycaster="enabled: true; far: 1; showLine: true; direction: 1 0 0; interval: 40;"  rotation="0 5 0" position="0.0 0.03 0.0" line="color: yellow; opacity: 0.8;"></a-entity>
    </a-entity>
```

Basically is a robot model with physics aplied, the robot has a camera and a raycaster, i need to disable the physics to the raycaster component but i don't know how.

Can someone help me?

Thank you all!.

Comment: did you try removing `dynamic-body` from the `#positionSensor` ?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski yes i tried but not works, seems #positionSensor inherits dynamic-body from #a-pibot

Comment: i'm not sure what you're trying to achieve - in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/dskxn4fr/2/) there is a parent with a `dynamic-body` and a child which is not acting like another dynamic body. What should be going on here to match your expectations ?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski In the fiddle you linked to me the sphere is moving with the red box and collides with other entities, try adding this line to the code and see.

<a-box dynamic-body position="0 3 0"></a-box>

What i want is that my raycaster entity doesn't inherit the dynamic-body property from the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't disable the propagation of a `dynamic-body` over child entities, so you can make your raycaster "follow" the pibot like this:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  init: function() {
    this.pibot = document.querySelector(#pibot)
  },
  tick: function() {
    this.el.setAttribute("position", pibot.getAttribute("position"))
  }
})
```

**HTML**

Like i did [here](http://this.elToFollow.getAttribute(%22position%22)).